# Fail test on SAWarning

Tags: python, testing, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I'm using Pyramid and SQLAlchemy and I have a bunch of tests. From time to time, I notice SAWarnings being issued while tests run. I hunt them down and make them go away.

The most common SAWarning I see is:

```
......eggs/SQLAlchemy-0.9.3-py2.7.egg/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py:562: SAWarning: Unicode type received non-unicode bind param value.
```

Now, I'd like my test suite to fail immediately after a SAWarning is found. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the [python warnings filter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html):

```
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter("error")
```

Comment: I used warnings.simplefilter("error", category=sqlalchemy.exc.SAWarning) in the end, to filter only SAWarnings, but still, a very good answer.